# Airy integral with complex coefficients

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, airy-functions

In the book by Olivier Vallee and Manuel Soares about Airy function following integral has been given:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left({\rm i}
\left({{t^{3} \over 3} + at^{2} + bt}\right)\right)
{\rm d}t
=
2\pi\exp\left({\rm i}a\left({2a^{2} \over 3} - b\right)\right)\operatorname{Ai}\left(b - a^{2}\right)
$$
I wonder if this is valid or not when $a$ is complex. Anyone knows $?$.

Comment: If the imaginary part of $a$ is non-zero, it seems you would get as an integrant with a factor of the form $e^{-t^2 \Im(a)}$ which would probably make the integral diverge.

Comment: But it is will be a Gaussian with coefficient negative.

Comment: @ThibautDumont By the way why my question isn't presented in the main page?

Comment: Good point! (It does show on the main page, at least for me.)

Comment: The rhs should be $2 \pi e^{i a (2 a^2/3 - b)} \operatorname{Ai}(b - a^2)$.