# Translation property of the Airy transform for complex values

Tags: integration, complex-integration, airy-functions

Airy transform is defined as follows:

$$ f_a(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm{Ai}(t-x)dt $$

According to the book by  Olivier Vallee and Manuel Soares it has the translation property: $f_a(x+c)$ is the Airy transform of $f(x+c)$. I can see that this is valid by just change of variables. The integration limits won't change. However if the translation is complex valued then the integration limits would be shifted in the complex domain:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+ic)\mathrm{Ai}(t-x)dt= \int_{-\infty+ic}^{\infty+ic}f(t')\mathrm{Ai}(t'-(x+ic))dt' $$

So my question is that if the translation property is valid for the complex shift?

I am particularly interested in the case where $f$ is a Gaussian function. I have numerically checked and it seems that it is valid.

Comment: What have you tried so far to answer your question? Have you tried the simplest examples?

Comment: Actually I am only interested in the special case that $f$ is Gaussian. Think it as a Fourier transform of shifted Gaussian function then you have this complex shifted Gaussian function. I have tried many related problems which always led to a similar end. Check also my other related questions: [question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156664/airy-integral-with-complex-coefficients) , [question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666709/integration-limits-in-the-integral-form-of-airy-function-with-complex-argument) .

Comment: **Is** the translation property valid for the examples you tried?

Comment: I couldn't prove it analytically but numerically it seems like it holds.

Comment: Good to know. So you are **conjecturing** the property is valid based on some numerical examples. **Please** include that  information in your question text.

Comment: Is this transformation defined for all **complex** functions?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe you can see better using the preview in google books: [Airy](https://books.google.cz/books?id=Rms5FnMuKEgC&lpg=PR1&hl=tr&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q&f=false)